# Android camera access

Tags: linux

I mean if when one app is using camera in background , is using another camera app at the same time possible??

Some people say it depends on how the applications is coded.

Also the app “sound assistant” makes 2 music apps using speaker at the same time.
And there are apps that use front and back camera simultaneously.
Then, access to camera by 2apps at the sametime can be possible??

Any way thanks for reading and I want to know if the phone is rooted or an app has root permission , there would be a change in answer:)

I wonder in rooted android phone, this can be possbile .

Btw i am talking in android version 5.0-6.0 which was released 2015-2016.